# Converting a Scala List to a JavaFX ObservablesList using setData method

Tags: java, scala, javafx, jvm, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX.

I have a list of observations in a Scala List, of type List[(Int, Int)].

I want to somehow convert this list into one that can be used by the JavaFX setData method:

```
import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
import javafx.stage.Stage
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

// in a main class somewhere:


val series1: XYChart.Series[Number, Number] = new XYChart.Series()
series1.setName("Portfolio 1")

// this is the list of my values
val list: List[XYChart.Data[Int, Int]] = List();

// I want to convert this to an observable list that I can pass into setData
val observableList: ObservableList[XYChart.Data[Number, Number]] = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list)

series1.setData(observableList)
```

This throws a type error as expected:

```
found   : List[javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data[Int,Int]]
[error]  required: javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data[Number,Number]
```

So my question is, is there a way to do what I want. I know there is a getData method, but I really want to figure out how to use setData instead.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL/DR

This works:

```
import javafx.collections.{FXCollections, ObservableList}
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

def convert[A <:B, B ](in: XYChart.Data[A,A]): XYChart.Data[B,B] =
  in.asInstanceOf[XYChart.Data[B, B]]

val series1: XYChart.Series[Number, Number] = new XYChart.Series()
series1.setName("Portfolio 1")

val list:  List[XYChart.Data[Integer, Integer]] = List()
// list: List[javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data[Integer,Integer]] = List()

val convertedList = list.map( convert[ Integer, Number ] ).asJava
//convertedList: java.util.List[javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data[Number,Number]] = []

val observableList: ObservableList[XYChart.Data[Number, Number]] =
  FXCollections.observableArrayList( convertedList )
//observableList: javafx.collections.ObservableList[javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Data[Number,Number]] = []

series1.setData( observableList )
series1
//res2: javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.Series[Number,Number] = Series[Portfolio 1]
```

#### Breakdown

To make this work, we need a way to transform the list you're trying to add from `List[XYChart.Data[ Int, Int ] ]` into `List[ XYChart.Data[ Number, Number ] ]`, like so:

```
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

val convertedList = list.map( convert[ Int, Number ] ).asJava
val observableList: ObservableList[ XYChart.Data[ Number, Number ] ] =
  FXCollections.observableArrayList( convertedList )

def convert[A, B]( in: XYChart.Data[A,A]): XYChart.Data[B,B] = ???
```

#### Upcasting

Java's `XYChart.Data< Integer, Integer >` is auto converted to `XYChart.Data[ Int, Int ]`. While `java.lang.Integer` may be a subclass of `java.lang.Number`, `scala.Int` isn't. To make it one, we need to revert every `Int` back to an `Integer`.

Even so, adding an `X[ Integer ]` to `X[ Number ]` is covariant, while `XYChart.Data< X, Y >` is invariant. Unfortunately, digging into the Data-class isn't going to help. We can't override (final), it hasn't got a copy constructor, and simply extracting its values breaks the idea behind fx's property-based approach. So, we sort of stuck. However, casting is relatively safe here, as long as we continue to use it as a property-chain:

```
def convert[A <:B, B ](in: XYChart.Data[A,A]): XYChart.Data[B,B] =
  in.asInstanceOf[XYChart.Data[B, B]]
```

Comment: thanks, definitely enjoyed reading the explanation and learnt a lot too!